# Widget Not Updating Information from shared_preferences in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-sharedpreference

I was making a settings page for my flutter app to save a single number. I used shared_preferences. It can save the value into saved_preferences, and it can retrieve the data, but when settings page is loaded again it doesn't load the data into the widget. Here are some pictures to show what is happening.

[Here is when I first enter the settings page, the max value in dart is set to null and the key in the shared_preferences doesn't exist.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMOJc.png)

[Here is after I input a value, the max value in dart is 7574 and a key called max with the value 7574.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duQdP.png)

[Here is after I exit the page and come back. The max value in dart is null but the shared_preferences data is still 7574.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWSht.png)

I believe it has something to do with the async, because the widgets are already loading without it first getting the data from shared_preferences. But I don't know why the setState() wouldn't handle that after the data has loaded.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Settings extends StatefulWidget {
  const Settings({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Settings> createState() => _SettingsState();
}

class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {
  late SharedPreferences preferences;
  int? max;

  _loadMax() async {
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!preferences.containsKey('max')) {
      _setMax(16);
    } else {
      max = preferences.getInt('max');
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  _setMax(int value) async {
    await preferences.setInt('max', value);
    max = value;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (max == null) _loadMax();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Max Number (Inclusive) ',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 50,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Maximum',
                      counterText: '',
                    ),
                    initialValue: max.toString(),
                    inputFormatters: [
                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"[0-9.]")),
                    ],
                    onFieldSubmitted: (s) {
                      _setMax(int.parse(s));
                    },
                    maxLength: 4,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: const Text('Home'),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Settings extends StatefulWidget {
  const Settings({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Settings> createState() => _SettingsState();
}

class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {
  late SharedPreferences preferences;
  int? max;
  TextEditingController textFeildData = TextEditingController();

  _loadMax() async {
    preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (!preferences.containsKey('max')) {
      _setMax(16);
    } else {
      textFeildData.text = preferences.getInt('max').toString();
      print(textFeildData);
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  _setMax(int value) async {
    await preferences.setInt('max', value);
    max = value;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // if (max == null) _loadMax();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              'Max Number (Inclusive) ',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 10.0),
            SizedBox(
              width: 100,
              height: 50,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: textFeildData,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  // labelText: 'Maximum',
                ),
                // initialValue: max.toString(),
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r"[0-9.]")),
                ],
                onFieldSubmitted: (s) {
                  _setMax(int.parse(s));
                },
                maxLength: 4,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
          child: const Text('Home'),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

hopefully this will help just give textfield a controller and do what ever you want with the field text